# Get excel sheet name from ByteStream in Python

Tags: python, excel, bytesio

I have an excel file with multiple sheet name.
I have converted that file into bytestream using BytesIO.
Now I want to get sheet names from the converted bytestream.
Is there any way I can get sheet names from bytestream.

Thanks,

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: So I am reading an excel file from my source and using ByteIO I am converting into stream using following code      'stream = BytesIO(response.content)'.The excel file has two sheets and I want to read one of the sheet and convert into data frame.I want to read one of the two sheet and discard one.